# Telegram Bot C#: Выдаёт ошибку при попытке запроса botClient.GetMeAsync().Result

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, бот, c#-8.0

Вот код Main:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Console Settings:
            Console.Title = $"Telegram bot logger 2.0. Console Started at: {DateTime.Now}.";
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            //Bot Main Code
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Telegram Bot. Please Wait... (Timeout = 21.5 Seconds)");
            botClient = new TelegramBotClient(TOKEN, PROXY) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(21) };
            Console.WriteLine("Bot Succsessfuly started! And working ONLINE");
            var me = botClient.GetMeAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"Collected bot info : bot id: {me.Id}. Bot Name: {me.FirstName}. Bot Username: {me.Username}.");
            Console.WriteLine($"Started new logging from {DateTime.Now}. To stop bot and simple logger type 'stop' or 'exit'.");
            Console.WriteLine("Now you can type commands.");

            botClient.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;

            botClient.StartReceiving();

            while (isStopping != true)
            {
                string line = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                if (line == "exit" || line == "stop")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Stopping Bot...");
                    isStopping = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");

                }
                else if (line == "help")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(helpDoc);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Recived unkown command: '{line}'. Type 'help' if you don't understand what do!");
                }
            }
        }
```

Проблема заключается в том что при попытке запроса

```cs
var me = botClient.GetMeAsync().Result;
```

System.AggregateException: "127.0.0.1:54297g:4432.0. Cons"
Внутреннее исключение:
HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
Подробности:
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Сообщение = One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).)
  Источник = System.Private.CoreLib
  Трассировка стека:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at TelegramBot.ConsoleBot.Main(String[] args)

Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов:
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()

Внутреннее исключение 1:
HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).

Скриншоты:
[image: Ошибка]

[image: Кусок кода с Proxy.]

Comment: вы получаете в ответ на запрос ошибку - Internal Server Error, разбирайтесь с тем сервисом, куда вы отправляете запрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*500 (Internal Server Error, Внутренняя ошибка сервера) — код статуса в протоколе HTTP, сообщающий, что серверная программа запущена, но работает с серьёзными внутренними ошибками, препятствующими нормальной обработке запроса клиента. Ошибка должна быть исправлена на стороне сервера*

> System.AggregateException: "127.0.0.1:54297g:4432.0.

Явная ошибка при подключении к Proxy, некорректный порт